# From trigger beforeInsert how to stop the insert in the database table

Tags: apex

Is there a possibilty in Salesforce from trigger beforeInsert how to stop the insert in the database table.

Answer (score 9):

Using the SObject method [addError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError) on a record will prevent any DML operations (including inserts) from occurring on that record.

```
trigger preventContactInserts on Contact (before insert) {
  for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
    if (c.FirstName=='Brian' && c.LastName=='Mansfield') {
      c.addError('You can't insert this record.');
    }
  }
}
```